# the use of seeks and sought

Tags: irregular-verbs

I will like to know the various uses of seek and its past participle sought. for instance, is it right to say;

1. It is advisable the secretary seeks clearance from her boss before issuing permit.  OR
2. It is advisable the secretary sought clearance from her boss before issuing permit.

Comment: You can't offer advice (how to do something) on something hat has already happened. The question is moot and therefore the advice is irrelevant. You could say "*It **would have been** for the secretary to have sought*...".  Also, while "*... the secretary seek**s***..." is ok, you might prefer "*the secretary seek*" (no `s`).

Comment: Both are wrong. It should be "It is advisable that the secretary seek", but it would be simpler to say "The secretary should seek".

Answer (score 2):

It depends if your intention is to construct a finite phrase or non-finite phrase.

#### What is a non-finite element?

A non-finite element is akin to a stateless modular function in Mathematics and Computer Science.

Given a function *f(x,y)*, you can catenatively use that function without limitation except that you conform to the parameters x and y, without needing to modify the innards of the module *f(x,y)*.

Exemplifying non-finite elements, notice that the non-finite phrase can be deployed regardless the time, gender, plurality of subjects.

- She came here *to die*.
- 2000 years ago, came here *to die*.
- I know that next year they will come here *to die*.
- I had thought that the Australian man told me that he came here *to die*.
- I prefer she *having her breakfast before lunch*.
- 3000 years ago, people did prefer *having their breakfast before lunch*.
- Next year, I will still prefer *having breakfast before lunch*.

Non-finite elements can be either

- infinitives
- gerunds
- participles
- subjunctive clauses

Subjunctive clauses are an interesting mode of non-finite elements. Subjunctive clauses disconnect themselves from the grasp of real time into imaginary time. Most subjunctive clauses use the past or past perfect tenses to detach themselves from real time to float into imaginary time. However, that is not a necessity, because as long as you can float a phrase into imaginary time even without the modification of tenses, that would constitute use of subjunctive mood/mode.

Let's look at your sentences and imbue some intention into them.

#### With finite intention.

You wish to convey an observation being carried out just once and at only one particular time, and therefore is not independent of time, or number.

1. I will ensure that the secretary seeks clearance from her boss before issuing that permit, tomorrow.
2. It is advisable that the secretary seeks clearance from her boss tomorrow before issuing that permit we are reviewing.

#### With non-finite intention.

You wish to introduce an instruction that will apply anytime, any place, any number of actors.

1. It is advisable that the secretary *seek clearance* from her boss before issuing a permit.
2. It is advisable that secretaries *seek clearance* from their bosses before issuing any permit.
   It is advisable that secretaries always *seek clearance* from their bosses before issuing any permit.

#### With imaginary non-finite intention.

Subjunctive/imaginary situations are a continuum of possibilities and it is not possible to classify all of them. However, some more common imaginary or subjunctive situations are situations when

- you are not sure if an event would happen but you wish to talk about it
- you know would happen but do not wish to restrict its applicability to anytime or anyone
- you are making a proposal without caring if it is needed
- having a fantasy dreaming about stuffs that certainly will never happen
- you know a situation would happen, but deliberately make it imaginary to be sarcastic
- you know a situation would happen, but deliberately cast it as imaginary to be polite in making a request, to let the other party know that they are not obliged to fulfill the request.

1. It is advisable that the secretary sought clearance from her boss before issuing such permits, regardless the town council's decision on having such permits.
2. Should the Supreme Court decide on gay marriages, it is advisable that town clerks sought advice from their Bible before issuing a marriage licence. (just kiddin)
3. "It is better if you ate caviar." the princess said to her servant who had expressed that servants' breakfast in the palace was unfit for consumption.
4. "Could I have the freshest meat cuts, please." she was hoping the butcher would be charmed by her pretty smile.
5. "Could I have a glass of water?" the princess instructed her maid politely.
6. "Could I have a glass of actual water?" the princess scolded her maid as she poured the murky glass of liquid on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trend in English to reduce the number of irregular verbs. I guess there are about 25o irregular verbs, not counting compound verbs as befall etc. In spoken language a good many of these 250 verbs are not used. 
"to seek" has been replaced by to look for. Reducing the number of irregular forms is a normal and constant process. So one has the impression that "to seek" is being pushed aside. You find it in novels and in some fixed expressions as "to seek revenge".